# Green's theorem vector form interal

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I use the fact that the integral is equal to $divF = sint-cost$ . Now I'm supposed to integrate that w.r.t. to the area, which is $dA=dydx$ . I then try to replace $\frac{dy}{dt}=-sint$ . I do the same for dx and get $dx=-cosdt$ The integral is now a double integral with 2 dt's. I don't think it's right. Also how would I compute the limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area calculations using Green's theorem can go as follows,
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Area} &=& \int \int dA \\
            &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{C} x dy - y dx
\end{eqnarray}
And take it from there.

Comment: I forgot about this method. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, Nick.